# theme_preprocess_menu is not seeing main menu

Tags: theming, hooks, navigation

Background:  I have an event website where I want to hide the event registration menu item when registration for the event is closed.

theme_preprocess_menu is not triggering on anything except 'menu__toolbar'.  The code:

```
function myTheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
  dpm($hook);
}
```

merely gives the result "menu__toolbar" on any page where my theme is active.  My theme is based on Bartik.

How do I get it to trigger on the main menu?

Comment: It's just `hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables)` without `$hook` and then `dpm($variables);`. Theme name must only contain lower case letters and underscores. Did you flush cache? Does the same hook get triggered from a custom module? Where exactly did you place the hook? Is the main menu currently visible on the page you are checking? Update your question for clarification.

Comment: Try with **[hook_menu_links_discovered_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/9.3.x)**

Comment: But the more appropriate solution would be to deny access with **[hook_entity_access](https://www.prometsource.com/blog/how-manage-hook-entity-access-with-drupal)**, as when access is forbidden, it hides the link automatically.

Comment: Preprocess functions receive three arguments from [`ThemeManager::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/function/ThemeManager%3A%3Arender/9.3.x), which calls them as `$preprocessor_function($variables, $hook, $info);`. The value of `$hook` is also stored in `$variables['theme_hook_original']`, though; there isn't any need to use the second parameter, and that's why preprocess functions don't usually use it.

Comment: To hide a menu item, it's better to change its #access value, as @NoSssweat said. A preprocess function would be too late for this, and it would be the wrong hook to use, since its purpose is changing how an element is rendered.

Comment: Thanks very much.  hook_entity_access solves one of my problems neatly (the one I described above).   There is one other menu item I would like to hide but not disable:  'login'.  Once the event is closed, nobody except admin needs to login, so I would like to hide it, but still allow admin to use /user/login to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

What you get in `$hook` doesn't say for which menu the preprocess function is called. It's simple a suggestion Drupal is picking up in [`ThemeManager::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/function/ThemeManager%3A%3Arender/9.3.x).

```php
  // Invoke hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
  $suggestions = $this->moduleHandler->invokeAll('theme_suggestions_' . $base_theme_hook, [
    $variables,
  ]);

  // If the theme implementation was invoked with a direct theme suggestion
  // like '#theme' => 'node__article', add it to the suggestions array before
  // invoking suggestion alter hooks.
  if (isset($info['base hook'])) {
    $suggestions[] = $hook;
  }

  // Invoke hook_theme_suggestions_alter() and
  // hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
  $hooks = [
    'theme_suggestions',
    'theme_suggestions_' . $base_theme_hook,
  ];
  $this->moduleHandler->alter($hooks, $suggestions, $variables, $base_theme_hook);
  $this->alter($hooks, $suggestions, $variables, $base_theme_hook);

  // Check if each suggestion exists in the theme registry, and if so,
  // use it instead of the base hook. For example, a function may use
  // '#theme' => 'node', but a module can add 'node__article' as a suggestion
  // via hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter(), enabling a theme to have
  // an alternate template file for article nodes.
  foreach (array_reverse($suggestions) as $suggestion) {
    if ($theme_registry->has($suggestion)) {
      $info = $theme_registry->get($suggestion);
      break;
    }
  }
```

[`olivero_theme_suggestions_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21olivero%21olivero.theme/function/olivero_theme_suggestions_menu_alter/9.3.x) is one of the hooks that alter the suggestions for the menu template file. There could be a module doing a similar suggestion, in your case.

```php
function olivero_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['attributes']['region'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'menu__' . $variables['attributes']['region'];
  }
}
```

What you are looking for is the menu machine name, stored in `$variables['menu_name']` as documented in [menu.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21menu.html.twig/9.3.x).

If the purpose is hiding a menu item, using that preprocess hook is not the solution. To hide a menu item is sufficient, for example, to avoid the currently logged-in user has access to the route used for that menu item. In that case, Drupal won't show the menu item.